# How do I determine where chef is initially installed in my Vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

At the moment, I'm being tasked to work on a specific program. The problem is, the packaged Vagrant box, which holds all the code, that I was given to work with is not working.

It seems as though there are a number of things wrong with the way it is being provisioned, but I'll start with issue #1.

In the Vagrantfile within the directory, there is a chef provisioning script which reads a bunch of recipes and does it's usual business, however, for the provisioning to even work, it needs at least chef 11.* and the chef version installed is 10.0.*

I'm confused as to where chef 10 is even being installed in the first place on the Vagrant box to run the provisioning.

The vagrant box being used is saucy64.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find location of chef (or any other) executable with:

```
which chef
```

From man page `WHICH(1)`

```
NAME
     which -- locate a program file in the user's path

SYNOPSIS
     which [-as] program ...

DESCRIPTION
     The which utility takes a list of command names and searches the path for each executable file that would be run had
     these commands actually been invoked.

     The following options are available:

     -a      List all instances of executables found (instead of just the first one of each).

     -s      No output, just return 0 if any of the executables are found, or 1 if none are found.

     Some shells may provide a builtin which command which is similar or identical to this utility.  Consult the builtin(1)
     manual page.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the omnibus plugin for vagrant. This will automatically install the desired version of chef and remove the need for chef to be packaged within your vagrant box.

- https://github.com/chef/vagrant-omnibus